# Basis theorem for finite abelian groups question (Pinter's "A book of Abstract Algebra")

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am stuck at the exercise Q5 of Chapter 16. Here is a summary of the question:

Let $G$ be a finite Abelian $p$-group where $p$ is a prime. Let $a \in G$ be an element of highest possible order in $G$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $a$. Now $G/H$ = [$Hb_1$, $Hb_2$, ... $Hb_n$] and we can choose $b_i$ such that $ord(b_i) = ord(Hb_i)$ (this is proven in another exercise O).

The question is to prove that for any intergers $l_0, l_1, l_2,..., l_n$, if $a^{l_0}b_1^{l_1}b_2^{l_2}...b_n^{l_n} = e$, then $a^{l_0}=b_1^{l_1}=b_2^{l_2}=...=b_n^{l_n} = e$.

What I have tried: it looks like I need to use induction. So I started with simple cases.

If $n=0$ this is true.

If $n=1$, $a^{l_0}b_1^{l_1}=e$ means $(Ha^{l_0})(Hb_1^{l_1})=H$, which in turn gives $(Hb_1)^{l_1}=H$. So $l_1$ is a multiple of $ord(Hb_1)$, which is also a multiple of $ord(b_1)$. This indicates $b_1^{l_1}=1$.

If $n=2$, assume $a^{l_0}b_1^{l_1}b_2^{l_2}=e$. There are two cases, if $b_2^{l_2}=1$, by the $n=1$ case it's done. If, however, if $b_2^{l_2} \neq 1$, I am stuck. Trying the logic $(Hb_1^{l_1})(Hb_2^{l_2})=H$ and I cannot use the information that $ord(b_i) = ord(Hb_i)$.

I also notice that I haven't used the information that $G$ is a $p$-group, but I have struggled a few days without any progress. I've tried searching for proof and found a question on Q2, which unfortunately does not seem to help in my case. Could anyone shed some light on how to prove this? Appreciate your help!

Comment: There needs to be some further hypothesis on the generators $Hb_i$. For example let $G = \langle a, b \rangle \cong C_3 \times C_3$. Then $[Hb, Hb^2]$ is an admissible choice of generators for $G/H$ (deliberately redundant). The conclusion does not hold since $b \times b^2 = e$. So you are quite right to be stuck on the case $n=2$. This question might get closed because it is a bit basic for MathOverflow: if so I suggest you try Math.Stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks. I previously only had experience using stackoverflow so did not realize math overflow and math stackexchange are two different sites. I'll post there after I read the question again to see whether I'm missing anything. If someone knows how to close the problem please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinter gives a specific meaning to the notation $[\dotsc]$, namely, he writes $G = [a_1,\dotsc,a_n]$ if

1. Every $x \in G$ can be written as $x = a_1^{k_1} \dotsm a_n^{k_n}$ for some integers $k_n$,
2. if $a_1^{l_1} \dotsm a_n^{l_n} = e$ then $a_1^{l_1}=\dotsb=a_n^{l_n}=e$.

For the exercise you're asking about, you'll have to use that $G/H = [Hb_1,\dotsc,Hb_n]$ in this sense, plus $\operatorname{ord}(Hb_i) = \operatorname{ord}(b_i)$.

Comment: Just verified that $G/H=[Hb_i]$ can be proved. The key in understanding this question is that I can choose $Hb_i$, not that it must hold for any $Hb_i$. Will find some time this week to work out the question and accept the answer.

Comment: Turns out to be straightforwards. Starting from conclusion of Q3, apply the left multiplication of $H$, then use the property $ord(Hb_i)=ord(b_i)$ will complete the proof.

Comment: How do you prove that $G/H = [Hb_1,Hb_2,...,Hb_n]$? It's obvious that $G/H$ is finitely generated because $G$ is finite, but how do you show the second part, that if $(Hb_1)^{l_1}...(Hb_n)^{l_n} = H$ then $(Hb_1)^{l_1} = ... = (Hb_n)^{l_n} = H$? Does this require induction?

Comment: @NicholasCousar Use induction on the order of the abelian $p$-group. In this case, $G/H$ is an abelian $p$-group of smaller order than $G$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thanks! I tried using strong induction by assuming that the hypothesis was true for *all* groups with order less than $|G|$, not just abelian p-groups with order less than $|G|$, which did not get me anywhere. It feels kind of weird to use induction in this way because it feels like you are not proving the hypothesis for every natural number. But it makes more sense when you realize that the statement $P(k)$ that is actually being proved is "If $G$ is a finite abelian group of order $p^k$, then for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, the quotient group $G/H$ will be decomposable".